# QDataStream writing wrong values to QByteArray

Tags: c++, qt, qbytearray, qdatastream

I'm writing a simple TCP based network application in Qt and wanted to use `QDataStream` and `QByteArray` to send data over the network. The problem is that when I'm putting data into `QByteArray` they are "zeroed". For example (a slot in `MainWindow` that is connected to timer timeout signal):

```
void MainWindow::SendPlayer1Data(){
  QByteArray block;
  QDataStream s(&block, QIODevice::OpenModeFlag::ReadWrite);
  QString h="hello";
  s<<h;
  qDebug() << "h:        " << data;
  qDebug() << "block:    " << QString(block); // equivalent to s >> h on receiving end
  qDebug() << "block[0]: " << int(block[0]);
}
```

```
h:         "hello"
block:     ""
block[0]:  0
```

I receive `"hello"` once at the beginning but after that I only get `""`. The same goes for `qint32`. Both client and server shows that `QByteArray` size is 14 bytes, so `QDataStream` writes data into that array, but it makes them `0` (it shows `""` when I use `s >> h` and then use `qDebug() << h`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have figured it out.
The problem was not the `QByteArray` or socket because, as `@William Miller` mentioned, the data was there. 
The problem was with `QDataStream` on client side - I decided to create a new `QDataStream` object every time the slot responsible for receiving data was called. This way I was able to pack data easily into `QByteArray`, send it and receive every time.
The client function for receiving:

```
void ClientTcpHelper::ReceivePacket(){

if(socket.waitForReadyRead(20)){

    //qDebug()<<"Packet: "<<socket.peek(30)<<endl;
    qDebug()<<"Receiving packet!"<<endl;

    Data=socket.readAll();
    emit DataReceived();


}
else{
    //qDebug()<<"Failed to receive packet!"<<endl;

}}
```

and unpacking data to variables:

```
void ClientTcpHelper::UnpackData(){

stream=new QDataStream (&this->Data,QIODevice::OpenModeFlag::ReadWrite);
*stream>>h>>a>>b;
Data.clear();
delete stream;}
```

h,a and b are members of a class.

Unfortunately I can not explain why `QDataStream` need to be destroyed every time here in order to handle data as I wanted it from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is writing a `QString` directly to a stream that is expecting a `QByteArray`, consider the following

```
QByteArray block;
QDataStream s(&block, QIODevice::OpenModeFlag::ReadWrite);
QString h = "hello";
s << h;
qDebug() << block;
```

Which outputs

```
"\x00\x00\x00\n\x00h\x00""e\x00l\x00l\x00o"
```

So the data is there, it just isn't there how one might expect it. The easiest way to solve this is to create a `QByteArray` from a string encoded with UTF8 (or other encoding of your choice). This can trivially be done on the fly,

```
QByteArray block;
QDataStream s(&block, QIODevice::OpenModeFlag::ReadWrite);
QString h = "hello";
QByteArray data(h.toUtf8(), 5);
s << data;
qDebug() << block;
```

Which outputs

```
"\x00\x00\x00\x05hello"
```

Because when this `QByteArray` is sent through the `QDataStream` the length of the array and 3 `NULL` characters are prepended - the `NULL` characters are there in case the buffer is larger than a relatively small `5` (you can test that for yourself by passing a larger value - a small factor of 256 is most demonstrative - as the second parameter in the `QByteArray` constructor as this is the buffer length). But if you try to explicitly construct a `QString` (as `s >> h` does) from the `NULL`-commenced `QByteArray` it will create an empty string. To correct for this you can use `QByteArray::remove()` to remove the first `4` bytes like this

```
QByteArray block;
QDataStream s(&block, QIODevice::OpenModeFlag::ReadWrite);
QString h = "hello";
QByteArray data(h.toUtf8());
s << data;
qDebug() << QString::fromUtf8(block.remove(0, 4));
```

Which outputs

```
"hello"
```

---

## Complete example

```
#include <qbytearray.h>
#include <qdatastream.h>
#include <qdebug.h>

int main() {
  QByteArray block;
  QDataStream s(&block, QIODevice::OpenModeFlag::ReadWrite);
  QString h = "hello";
  QByteArray data(h.toUtf8());
  s << data;
  qDebug() << QString::fromUtf8(block.remove(0, 4));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution it gets the job done. But doesn't it make using QDataStream pointless if I have to get rid of NULL bytes manually? Shouldn't I write to QByteArray directly to write exactly what I want?

Comment: @Kestrel the point of the `QDataStream` is to serialize the data, but writing a `QByteArray` over serial requires sending a length - consider that you can send data that is not `NULL` terminated, without the length of the buffer you will get undefined behavior. It might be possible to send one byte at a time without any framing using `QDataStream::writeRawData()`, but I couldn’t get that to work so I excluded it from my answer.